# api route.ts return Response type with JSON from axios

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to make MSA so i want to use front server and backend server both.
So frontend calls api/route structure file api. and File api calls backend api with axios.
the problem is `return new Response(callAxios())` code keeps telling me red line error mark probably can not confirm type like JSON or String.
No problem with using cuz still i can get JSON data but how can i remove the red line error mark
I am not familiar with typescript and just started today.

[image]

```
import axios from "axios"

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response(callAxios())
}

async function callAxios(){
  await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/firstCall', {
    params: { // query string
      title: 'NEXT JS'
    },
    headers: { 
      'X-Api-Key': 'my-api-key'
    },
  }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      return res.data
  })
}
```

Remove the error mark and make sure accepting data type is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be aiming for something more like this:

```
import axios from "axios"

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return new Response(await callAxios())
}

async function callAxios(){
  const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/firstCall', {
    params: { // query string
      title: 'NEXT JS'
    },
    headers: { 
      'X-Api-Key': 'my-api-key'
    },
  });

  console.log(result, result.data);
  return result.data;
}
```

You either use `async` and `await` or you use callbacks, not both.

Comment: Thank you , amazingly works! but how can i handle exception case for axios catch?

Comment: when using `async` and `await` you surround it with `try` and `catch` as it'll throw on promise rejection

Comment: Thank you, for page component how can i parsing the json data? res.json() not working

Comment: export default async function Home()    {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/hello`)   
  const jsonData = res

Comment: `JSON.parse(jsonData)` as `JSON` is a built in object that provides the function `parse`

Comment: const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/hello`)
  const jsonData = res

  console.log('res')
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData)))

  //show res {}

Comment: If you are having to use `JSON.stringify` then it means `axios` has already parsed the json for you. I may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you. this stupid typescript doesnt let me jsonData to change directly use JSON.parse so i changed to String type. But another problem is, res returns empty object like {}. Is it beacuse asyncronous promblem again cuz Through three steps async ?

Comment: If you type this into your browser url, what do you get?
`http://localhost:8080/firstCall?title=NEXT%20JS`, or `http://localhost:3000/api/hello`

Comment: {"name":"mangdo","age":24}, I am using Spring Framewrok and could see inside api/route.ts before return from Get method.

Comment: when i call http://localhost:3000/api/hello it occurs 500 error.

Comment: I'd need to see more code to help debug. We have fixed your initial problem. I suggest you create another question describing your current problem in more detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75765799/spring-framework-and-nextjs-axios-data-transfer-problem

Comment: Here is my full code.