# Spring framework and nextjs axios Data Transfer problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, next.js

I want to  use Spring and Nextjs for project.

I used to make projects with Spring and React.

Nextjs 13 version provides api/route structrue so it is quite interesting compare with regular React framework.

When i use React, i used a container - presentaitonal pattern and write axios code in container Components.

Actually in Nextjs, i can use like that. But i want to manipulate data using by Next's api/route structure.

And it seems more beneficial to use for security reason using Next's structure.

The problem is i can not pass data below sequence.

Spring -> api/route -> pageComponent

I can pass the data below sequences.

Spring -> pageComponent

api/route -> pageComponent

Below are my Codes.

--- Spring

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("http://192.168.0.8:3000");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/firstCall")  
    @ResponseBody
    public HashMap<String,Object> firstCall(){
        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();    
        map.put("age", 24);
        map.put("name", "mangdo");
        return map;
    }

}
```

--- Next

```
//route.ts
import axios from "axios"
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  let call = await callAxios()
  return call
}

async function callAxios(){
  const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/firstCall', {
    params: { // query string
      title: 'NEXT JS'
    },
    headers: {
      'X-Api-Key': 'my-api-key'
    }
  })
  return result.data
}
```

```
//page.tsx
export default async function Home() {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/hello`)
  const jsonData = res

  console.log('res')
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData)))

  //show res {}
  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
    
    </main>
  )
}
```

Solve Spring and NextJS data Transfering problem.

Comment: could you try with the useEffect hook to fetch and set data to component state

Comment: i didnt. i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems app/api fetch can used by same node.js front server inside.
thats why it didnt retrun any backend data so i used client side axios code to call backend data.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @JayCold